# Server Error : Should we have to install webapp2 separately to run Google App Engine in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am following getting started guide of google app engine python2.7. I have downloaded zip file of app engine for my ubuntu. I have created helloworld files and ran

```
'google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/'
```

command. localhost:8000, i.e. admin page opens fine, but localhost:8080 has server error. 
I have tried to import in my local python environment, which gave an error. So do we have to install it? which I tried according to webapp2's official website but didn't work out.

Comment: Is it a 500 error? Do you have any additional information from the log/command line about the error? To answer the thread title, you shouldn't have to install webapp2 separately.

Comment: I'm using gentoo and never had any problems... no need to install anything other than the zipped SDK (maybe PIL). Post the error you are getting

Answer (score 2):

This question gets asked so many times, have you checked stackoverflow for similar answers?

Have you read the documentation on what third party libraries are included with the appengine runtime.

webapp2 is included in the runtime but you must configure support/inclusion in app.yaml

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

And before you get any further read up on how to include external third party libraries.  You will save yourself lots of time and questions just reading.